# Android 4.1 webview javascript not working.

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am having a function calling `javascript:alert('load')` attempting to show an alert box.
It is not working even I have already `setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    WebView wvMyWeb = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    wvMyWeb.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    wvMyWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_save:
            alertbox("Setting","Save Clicked");
            wvMyWeb.loadUrl("http://ec.m.zkiz.com");
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_load:
            wvMyWeb.loadUrl("javascript:alert('load')");
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: @Rob No, this is also not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not specify a chrome client, the [`WebChromeClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html) will fit your needs. Simply add this to your webview :

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

If you'd like to handle `alert` events in a particular way, you can also do :

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() { 
    @Override public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
        /* Do whatever you need here */
        return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: i fount this function on the internet too but my eclipse warn me that i don't have it.`The method setWebChromeClient(WebChromeClient) in the type WebView is not applicable for the arguments (new WebChromeClient(){})`

Comment: Make sure you did import the `android.webkit.WebChromeClient` in your class, also use `setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient())`, not `setWebChromeClient(WebChromeClient)`.

Comment: I can manually import android.webkit.WebChromeClient without problem.. thanks. no wonder why there is no quick-fix for that import @@